# Cron schedule based on database

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a product table, and an expired_date field.
I want to use cron-job, to send node-mailer about 1 week or 2 weeks before a product get expired, based from the expired_date field.
is this possible to do with cron?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can be done.

I suggest you create **one** CRON-JOB which execute **once** daily.

The CRON Job execute the task about checking your table about which product is expiring before 1 week or 2 weeks, then send the email if expiring product existed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [npm cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) to get this done. Run a daily job where you will be querying database to fetch all the expired results, send an email to users after fetching data.

```
const CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
const job = new CronJob('* * * */1 * *', () => {
  console.log('You will see this message every second');
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
job.start();
```